# Finding the corresponding position of an bracket

Tags: c++

Say, I have an string as:

```
command_a -abc -from { {A} {B} {C} {D} } -to { {A} {B} {C} {D} }
```

I want to replace the substring which is inside the curly braces of -from with some other string. So, after replacing string should become:

```
command_a -abc -from { <other_string> } -to { {A} {B} {C} {D} }
```

-from and -to could come in any order. There are more options, -thru, -extra which can come in the above string.

I have thought of one solution which uses the stack to solve this problem. Wondering if there are other solutions to it.

Comment: Stack is needed when you have multiple types of brackets and you want to make sure they're matched. If you already know the string contains no unmatched brackets *or* there is only one type of brackets, instead of a stack you can just use a single integer to keep track of the nesting level.

Comment: Since you have a clear separation with opening and closing of curly braces with `from` and `-to`, just locate their positions and use `string::replace`

Comment: @macroland that works fine until `A` is "-to"; or someone puts -abc between -from and -to

Comment: @UKMonkey Once you find the first `{` counter++ and then for `}` counter--  and when counter==0 the next character set can be checked whether it is `-to` or not

Comment: @macroland so now the -to or -from or -anythingelse doesn't matter; it's just the counter with {}

Comment: @macroland but now what if A is "foo{bar}"?  You can't just track {}; you now have to track quotes too; or maybe you want to escape it - so that you can have quotes in your string?  Creating a reliable parser isn't quite as trivial as you think.